# How to 'drop'/delete characters from in front of a string?

Tags: bash, shell, text-processing, sed

I have a string that I would like to manipulate. The string is `H08W2345678` how would I be able to manipulate it so the output is just `W2345678`?

Similarly if the I wanted to drop the last 4 characters from `H08W2345678` so that I get `H08W234` how would I do this?

Comment: There are many ways to manipulate strings. Is there a specific reason for using `sed` ?

Comment: @don_crissti No reason, apart from lack of experience. Any alternatives are welcome...

Comment: @don_crissti, the story: from a filtered down CSV file, I take one of the parameters from a line which is `H08W2345678` and need to manipulate it to `W2345678` This value with other datum will be put into an email sent off.  Thie emailing will be undertaken with cron.

Comment: @don_crissti  `awk`ing it. I create an array and then modify each of the element within the array (all differently - i.e change the Epoch timestaimp in seconds to a  date etc.)

Comment: You can do stuff like that with awk: `printf %s\\n "XX,H08W2345678,YY" | awk -F, '{print substr($2, 4); print substr($2, 1, length($2)-4)}'`

Answer (score 47, accepted):

Just using bash (or `ksh93` where that syntax comes from or `zsh`):

```
string="H08W2345678"

echo "${string:3}"
W2345678

echo "${string:0:-4}"
H08W234
```

See the Wooledge wiki for more on [string manipulation](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/100#Removing_part_of_a_string).

Comment: This requires bash 4.2 or higher.  See [this old copy of the Bash Reference Manual, Section 3.5.3, ‘‘Shell Parameter Expansion’’](https://bash.cyberciti.biz/bash-reference-manual/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html) or [chicks’s answer here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/249869/23408#249870 "Meaning of [ “${1:0:1}” = '-' ]") to see the old constraint (“*length* must evaluate to a number greater than or equal to zero.”); … (Cont’d)

Comment: (Cont’d) …  see [Bash changes (at the Bash Hackers Wiki)](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/scripting/bashchanges#quoting_expansions_substitutions_and_related) (scroll down to the bottom of the section) or [bash news at the Technology Infrastructure Services organization at Case Western Reserve University](http://tiswww.case.edu/php/chet/bash/NEWS) (search for “added to bash-4.2” and then scroll down to “q.”) to see the revision.  … … … … ```"${string:0:${#string}-4}"``` works in bash version 4.1 as long as the length of `$string` is at least 4.

Comment: P.S. This will also choke on strings like `abc-e`, where, when you drop the first three characters, you are left with `-e` (because `echo -e` doesn’t do what you would want).

Answer (score 17):

```
$ echo "H08W2345678" | sed 's/^.\{3\}//'
W2345678
```

`sed 's/^.\{3\}//'` will find the first three characters by `^.\{3\}` and replace with blank. Here `^.` will match any character at the start of the string (`^` indicates the start of the string) and `\{3\}` will match the the previous pattern exactly 3 times. So, `^.\{3\}` will match the first three characters.

```
$ echo "H08W2345678" | sed 's/.\{4\}$//'
H08W234
```

Similarly, `sed 's/.\{4\}$//'` will replace the last four characters with blank (`$` indicates the end of the string).

Comment: Could you please explain the `'s/^.\{3\}//'` and `'s/.\{4\}$//'` as I am still learning sed, many thanks

Comment: @3kstc: Please check the edits

Comment: For just a few characters, I'd use `...` instead of `.\{3\}` since (to me) it's easier to read: `sed -e 's/^...//' -e 's/....$//'`  or in a single expression with alternation: `sed -r 's/^...|....$//g'`. If it were more than a few characters to delete, then I'd use the `/.\{17}\/` expression instead of `/.............../`.

Comment: This will behave badly if the string is `-e` or `-n`. Of course, the meaning of “drop the last 4 characters” is undefined for a string shorter than 4 characters, but, if somebody wanted to adapt this to drop the first or last ***one*** character, it could blow up.

Answer (score 5):

> #### How to 'drop'/delete characters from in front of a string?
>
> I have a string that I would like to manipulate. The string is H08W2345678 how would I be able to manipulate it so the output is just W2345678?

```
echo "H08W2345678" | cut -c 4-
```

> Similarly if the I wanted to drop the last 4 characters from H08W2345678 so that I get H08W234 how would I do this?

```
echo "H08W2345678" | cut -c -7
```

Comment: This only answers half of the question.

Comment: I believe your downvote is unfair. This half answers the question *I* had when I googled [*posix remove first characters*](https://www.google.com/search?q=posix+remove+first+characters) and this page showed up in search results. Moreover, this page title covers only that exact half of the question. I came back and contributed when I found the solution I liked - I think for that job `cut` is much more elegant than whatever else is on this page.

Comment: This solved my problem better than the rest of answers.

Comment: This answer is acceptable if you know the length of the string. If you don't you have to do extra math to calculate how to cut the characters at the end.

Answer (score 2):

If you have a file in which every line is
an eleven-character (or whatever) string that  you want to chop up,
`sed` is the tool to use. 
It’s fine for manipulating a single string, but it’s overkill. 
For a single string, [Jason’s answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/194936/23408#194938) is probably the best,
if you have access to bash version 4.2 or higher. 
However, the `${parameter:offset}`
and `${parameter:offset:length}` syntaxes
appear to be unique to bash (well, bash, ksh93, mksh, and zsh) —
I don’t see them
in [The Open Group Base Specifications for Shell Command Language](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_06_02). 
If you’re stuck with a POSIX-compliant shell
that doesn’t support substring expansion (extraction), you can use

```
$ printf "%s\n" "${string#???}"
W2345678

$ printf "%s\n" "${string%????}"
H08W234
```

using `printf` instead of `echo` to guard against strings like `abc-e`,
where, when you drop the first three characters, you are left with `-e`
(and `echo -e` doesn’t do what you would want).

And, if you’re not using a Bourne-family shell at all
(or you’re using an ancient, pre-POSIX system), these should still work:

```
$ expr " $string" : ' ...\(.*\)'
W2345678

$ expr " $string" : ' \(.*\)....'
H08W234
```

The extra leading space is to avoid problems with values of `$string`
that are actual `expr` operators (e.g., `+`, `/`, `index` or `match`)
or options (e.g., `--`, `--help` or `--version`).

Comment: @Stéphane Chazelas: (1) Thanks for reminding me of a pitfall that I knew about 40 years ago and somehow managed to forget. (2) I always used to solve this with `X`; e.g., `expr "X$string" : 'X...\(.*\)'`.  IMO, that’s easier to read and understand.  Is there any problem with that, or any reason to prefer a space? (3) Today I learned that ``expr + "$string" : '...\(.*\)'`` now works.  I don’t remember that from 40 years ago; is it sufficiently widely used to be safe to recommend? (4) You missed a note on jasonwryan’s answer and a nit-pick on heemayl’s answer.

Comment: AFAIK, that `expr +` is GNU only (won't work on Solaris nor FreeBSD AFAICS). I use space instead of x as it's less likely that some `expr` implementation would have operators that start with space  than with `x` and also because it's less likely there be collating elements that start with space than with `x`. But then I realise it's probably not a good choice for `expr " $a" "<" " $b"` for string comparison as some implementations end up doing numerical comparison when `$a`/`$b` look like numbers. Maybe `expr "@@$a"...` or `expr "x $a"` could be safer.

Answer (score 1):

With:

```
string="H08W2345678"
```

Matching 3 or 4 characters seems simple (for most shells):

```
$ printf '%s\t%s\n' "${string#???}" "${string%????}"
W2345678      H08W234
```

For the older shells (like the Bourne shell), use:

```
$ string=H08W2345678

$ expr " ${string}" : " ...\(.*\)"
W2345678

$ expr " ${string}" : " \(.*\)...." '
H08W234
```

If it is needed a numeric count of characters, use:

```
$ expr " ${string}" : " .\{3\}\(.*\)"
W2345678

$ expr " ${string}" : " \(.*\).\{4\}" '
H08W234
```

Of course, those regex work also with sed, awk and bash 3.0+:

```
$ echo "$string" | sed 's/^.\{3\}//'
W2345678

$ echo "$string" | sed 's/.\{4\}$//'
H08W234

$ echo "$string" | awk '{sub(/^.{3}/,"")}1'
W2345678

$ echo "$string" | awk '{sub(/.{4}$/,"")}1'
H08W234

$ r='^.{3}(.*)$'; [[ $a =~ $r ]] && echo "${BASH_REMATCH[1]}"
W2345678

$ r='^(.*).{4}$'; [[ $a =~ $r ]] && echo "${BASH_REMATCH[1]}"
H08W234
```