# Meaning of [ "${1:0:1}" = '-' ]

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I have the following script to launch a MySQL process:

```
if [ "${1:0:1}" = '-' ]; then
    set -- mysqld_safe "$@"
fi

if [ "$1" = 'mysqld_safe' ]; then
    DATADIR="/var/lib/mysql"
...
```

What does 1:0:1 mean in this context?

Comment: I'd really like to know the answer, but I feel this is a bit of a too narrow question for SF. I'm voting to migrate it to the Unix site.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

It's a test for a `-` dashed argument option, apparently. It's a little strange, really. It uses a non-standard `bash` expansion in an attempt to extract the first and only the first character from `$1`. The `0` is the head character index and the `1` is string length. In a `[` `test` like that it might also be:

```
[ " -${1#?}" = " $1" ]
```

Neither comparison is particularly suited to `test` though, as it interprets `-` dashed arguments as well - which is why I use the leading space there.

The best way to do this kind of thing - and the way it is usually done - is :

```
case $1 in -*) mysqld_safe "$@"; esac
```

Comment: Close; the number following the second colon in `${1:0:1}` is a length, not an index.

Comment: In a bashism way with `[[`: `[[ $1 == -* ]]`.

Comment: Personally I don't think those `-` will be a problem for `test` here.. [POSIX](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/test.html) gives definitions of the meanings by argument count. Since there is no such option that takes two arguments, it should be safe to write it in raw.

Comment: @Arthur2e5 - you're right - they shouldn't be a problem - and very likely are not problematic at all. it's still a strange way to go at it - it just doesn't fit well. what does `[[ : [[` do?

Comment: @mikeserv Well you should look at the webpage (if you are reading this from elsewhere).. My comment was like 'with START_CODE[[END_CODE: START_CODE[[ $1 == -*]]END_CODE'. The first `[[` is just the syntax name, and the colon is just a punctuation.

Answer (score 11):

This is going to take a substring of `$1` from the 0th to the 1st character.  So you're going to get the first character and only the first character of the string.

From the `bash` 3.2 man page:

> ```
>   ${parameter:offset}
>   ${parameter:offset:length}
>           Substring  Expansion.   Expands  to  up to length characters of
>           parameter starting at the character specified  by  offset.   If
>           length is omitted, expands to the substring of parameter start-
>           ing at the character specified by offset.   length  and  offset
>           are  arithmetic  expressions (see ARITHMETIC EVALUATION below).
>           length must evaluate to a number greater than or equal to zero.
>           If  offset  evaluates  to a number less than zero, the value is
>           used as an offset from the end of the value of  parameter.   If
>           parameter  is  @,  the  result  is length positional parameters
>           beginning at offset.  If parameter is an array name indexed  by
>           @ or *, the result is the length members of the array beginning
>           with ${parameter[offset]}.  A negative offset is taken relative
>           to  one  greater than the maximum index of the specified array.
>           Note that a negative offset must be separated from the colon by
>           at  least  one space to avoid being confused with the :- expan-
>           sion.  Substring indexing is zero-based unless  the  positional
>           parameters are used, in which case the indexing starts at 1.
> ```

Answer (score 8):

It is testing that the first character of the first argument `$1` is a dash `-`.

The 1:0:1 are the values for the parameter expansion: `${parameter:offset:length}`.

That means:

- Name: the parameter named `1`, i.e: `$1`
- Start: from the first character `0` (numbered from 0).
- Length: for 1 character.

In short: the first character of the first positional parameter `$1`.
That parameter expansion is available in ksh, bash, zsh (at least).

---

If you want to change the test line:

```
[ "${1:0:1}" = "-" ]
```

#### Bash options

Other safer bash solutions may be:

```
[[ $1 =~ ^- ]]
[[ $1 == -* ]]
```

Safer because this have no issues with quoting (no split is executed inside `[[`)

#### POSIXly options.

For older, less capable shells, could be changed to:

```
[ "$(echo $1 | cut -c 1)" = "-" ]
[ "${1%%"${1#?}"}"        = "-" ]
case $1 in  -*) set -- mysqld_safe "$@";; esac
```

Only the case command is more resistant to wrong quoting.